# How to fix errors android.annotation. in Handler.java?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This is what is constantly in the log, when I try to run my application on Android lolipop 5. On later versions of android it runs without any problems.

It refers to `Handler.java` and other files, which are all in error by default.

Even reinstalling the program and SDK from scratch didn't help.

How to solve this problem? I even tried rewriting Import under Androidx, doesn't help.

[Handler.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kh42F.png)
[Handler.java (2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQ1DI.png)

`at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class android.widget.ScrollView at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633) at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55) at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682) at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741) at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482) at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:775) at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:197)`

I do not understand why Android Studio, installed by default, immediately comes with errors that need to be corrected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error has nothing to do with the handler class,

the error is

> Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class android.widget.ScrollView

It cannot inflate your layout so you should check it for errors